# Undefined Variable $query PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Alguien me puede decir qué está mal en mi código?
Soy novato en esto :/
Según yo no hay errores, ya que luego defino la variable `$query`, pero me salta este error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: query in C:\xampp\htdocs\redsocial\login.php on line 68
```

Este es mi código:

```html
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($query, $_POST['usuario']);
$contrasena = mysqli_real_escape_string($query, trim(strip_tags(md5($_POST['contrasena']))));
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND contrasena = '$contrasena'");
```

Comment: Está definida así:
`mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND contrasena = '$contrasena'");` si a eso te refieres

Comment: exacto, ya revisé documentación y todo, pero no encuentro solución, ni error alguno :/, la variable `connect` la tengo en otro archivo

Comment: en donde estas definiendo $query antes de la linea $usuario y $contraseña?

Comment: Podrias incluir el codigo completo donde declaras la variable `$query` veo esta definida pero antes de definirla la estas solicitando por lo que no existiria aun

Comment: Es verdad, fué un error mío, mil disculpas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar `$query` (que aún no está definida, sino hasta dos líneas abajo, y es para otra cosa) por `$connect`.

Checa la documentación, le pasas el handler a la base de datos, no el query (que ni siquiera está definido cuando lo pasas)

```
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['usuario']);
$contrasena = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, trim(strip_tags(md5($_POST['contrasena']))));
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND contrasena = '$contrasena'");
```

Y siendo más puristas, `$query` no es el query, es el resultado del query. Normalmente yo lo codifico de la siguiente forma:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND contrasena = '$contrasena'";
$r = mysqli_query($db, $q) or die(mysqli_error($db) . "<br>$q");
while ($w = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    ...
}
```

Se que usar el `mysqli_error()` de esa forma no es lo más seguro, pero es como lo tengo en los ambientes de desarrollo, y me ayuda a encontrar problemas con la codificación del query. `$db` es el handler de la base de datos (`$connect` en tu caso), `$r` el resultado y `$w` (de row, pero como la `r` ya está usada, uso la `w`) el arreglo con los resultados.